# Arduino_DebugUtils.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors

How to get rid of this error?

```
/storage/emulated/0/ArduinoDroid/userlibraries/Arduino_ConnectionHandler/src/Arduino_ConnectionHandler.h:26:34: fatal error: Arduino_DebugUtils.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `Arduino_DebugUtils` library.

From [Arduino_DebugUtils](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduino_debugutils/):

> To use this library, open the [Library Manager](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries) in the Arduino IDE and install it from there.